# How to run web project by local IIS in visual studio express 2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I am new to visual studio and asp.net, Currently, I created a project and want to run that web project in Local IIS.

So I install the IIS, and checked it's working by open localhost.
Then I right clicked the project -> properties -> web.

On that page, I can only see two items (IIS Express and External Host) in the dropdown list in the Servers area.

My questions is how to make the Local IIS be available as well? Do I missing some setting, or it is because of the limitation of the version of visual studio I am using?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have no IIS installed on that machine. Go to "Install/Uninstall applications -> Turn on Windows Features" and make sure IIS checked.